# Encrypted files between OSX and Windows 10

Tags: encryption, multiple-computers

I need to securely encrypt a file on MacOS X but I'll need to be able to open the file on another OS, such as Windows 10.

I'd like to be able to use an easily shared key such as a passphrase.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want strong encryption that's available on basically any platform (including Windows & macOS), you should probably use [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) (a free-software replacement for PGP). Encryption's what it does, and it's pretty good.

It can use symmetric (password-only) encryption (`-c`) if you don't want to use or don't have private keys, but then the security depends a lot more on the password you use (so don't choose "password").

And it supports some compression too (algorithms like zip, zlip, bzip2, and options like `-z 9`).

Not that a program like 7zip isn't good too, but there are a lot of tiny mistakes that can seriously degrade security. I don't know if 7zip has been tested much, but apparently GPG/PGP [has stumped the Italian & British police, and the FBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Security_quality).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to compress the files that you wish to send using 7Zip
in a password-protected archive.

This is a cross-platform solution, since 7Zip is almost universally available.

Comment: yes but zipping and unzipping for large files takes long time